# How do I get the folder hierarchy on the same bar as my window controls(max, min, close)?

Tags: unity

[image]

In this image the controls for the apps (play, pause, folder hierarchy and the like. NOT file, edit, window, help etc...) are on the same "bar" as the the little traffic light window controls, the maximize, minimize and close buttons.

On my installation of Ubuntu 14.04 this does not happen.
I'm new to all of this really, I just want to save space on my screen so I would really appreciate a fairly detailed walkthrough of how this is done, or if it can be done on Ubuntu 14.04.